# Which implementation is hibernate's default for second level (L2) cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache

I understand what the L2 cache is, but I can find no docs that state what the default L2 cache implementation is.

Hibernate's docs say that the default impl was Ehcache prior to version 3.2, but they don't elaborate on what is now the default!

I found another person asking the same question in the Hibernate forums, but no one answered them: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2438906

Thanks ahead of time for a correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is [NoCacheProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cache/NoCacheProvider.html).  If you don't intentionally specify and set up some caching, there will be no caching, attempts to cache things are just ignored.